# Ports forwarding does not work for docker postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, manjaro

I want to set up a docker container with postgres database. To do this I use the following command:

`sudo docker run --name postgres-demo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`

Container starts and runs ok. I can use docker exec in it and run psql inside container.
Something is wrong with ports forwarding. When I try to execude command `psql` on my machine (outside container), I get a message: `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

My operating system is Manjaro 21.2.6.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect to the Postgres unix socket, rather than the TCP socket on port `5432`. You need to pass an appropriate `-h` argument to the `psql` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the hostname of postgre. The hostname of a container is usually `0.0.0.0`.

```
$ psql --help
  ...
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory (default: "local socket")
```

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
605b59525844   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   postgres-demo
```

```sh
$ psql --host=0.0.0.0 --username=postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1))
WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 14.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```